# Faster way to query Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two access tables, A and B:

```
Table A
Identifier BenefitBase    PlanNav   
1        131368.46      131368.46       
2        201768.8       201768.79
3        54057.46       54057.46    
4        7397.51        7397.51 
5        9931.4         9931.4  
6        178200         178200  
Table B
p      ValidityDate LockInAmount
1      2016-4       3.82
2      2016-4       19.97
3      2016-4       26.85
4      2016-6       34.95
```

I just want to create a query which extracts records from B where the "p" ID is not found in table A.
My current code is:

```
SELECT B.p, B.ValidityDate, B.LockInAmount
FROM B
WHERE (((B.p) Not In (select Identifier from A)));
```

Now to me, this code should work fine. However, because the tables are so large (B consists  of 486,000 rows (the "p"'s repeats in this table for different dates) whereas A consists of circa 19,000), whenever I run the query, access fills the query progress bar but freezes when near full.

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are both `B.p` and `A.Identifier` indexed?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by indexed. I don't see your answer anymore either :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a left join to do the same thing Gustav does. It's easier for me to read, and I believe that it will operate with the same execution plan.

```
select B.p, B.ValididtyDate, B.LockInAmount
from B
left join A on B.P = A.Identifier
where A.Identifier is null
```

And add to that the indexes recommended by Erik up above. (That said, if P and Identifier are primary keys on your tables then they are already indexed and you don't need to add the indexes)

Comment: best answer here as only one produced the results rather than freezing!

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know if the fields are indexed:
Create indexes for both fields (see [this page by Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce) for information on indexes):

Execute these queries to create the indexes (or use the GUI)

```
CREATE INDEX TblAIdentifier ON A(Identifier)

CREATE INDEX TblBP ON B(p)
```

As long as you at least create the first index, Access won't even need to open up table `A`. It can just look in the index which fields are taken.

You can use this answer together with the one provided by @Gustav

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, considering the tables are linked, I read it will be much slower when updating the tables so I've avoided this method. Will adopt this approach in other areas going forward.

Comment: Don't really get what you're saying. Indexes also speed up linked tables, only the indexes should be created in the database that contains the source tables. If you're linking from a non-Access database, the syntax to create an index might be different. The only reasons to not have indexes is if either you have no full access to the source, or if you're linking from something that doesn't support it like Excel (in which case you should fix that).

Comment: On that link you sent, under "Decide which fields to index", it states "Indexes can speed up searches and queries, but they can slow down performance when you add or update data." So I'm quite reluctant given the data is updated quite often and each update adds approx 10% to the total number of records. The tables are linked to csv files.

Comment: Well linked to csv counts as something that doesn't support indexes, so perhaps I wouldn't either. The increased time when updating and deleting is present, but minimal, just like when you add an extra field to a table. If you update or add a field linked to an index, the index needs to update too.

Answer (score 1):

You could "reverse" the seek - first find those that have a match, then exclude these from Table B:

```
Select B.*
From B
Where B.ID Not In
    (Select A.Id
    From A, B
    Where A.ID = B.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT B.p, B.ValidityDate, B.LockInAmount
FROM 
B 
Left join 
A
B.p=A.Identifier 
WHERE A.Identifier Is Null);